# Is there any example on how to use spring security with graphql-spqr?

Tags: graphql-spqr

Looking for example on how to implement spring boot role based authentication and authorization for graphql-spqr project using spring security.

Tried using spring-boot-starter-security but having issues while using playground. Getting below error

{
"error": "Unexpected end of JSON input"
}

[Click here to see error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAdfw.png)

Answer (score 0):

In general there's nothing special about how SPQR interacts with Spring Security. You set up your security the same as ever, and it should behave as expected. The error you're getting is a bit unfortunate, because Spring will normally return a body-less 401 when authorization fails, and playground expects a JSON body, hence the "Unexpected end of JSON input".

How do you normally authenticate to your server? Session cookie? Access token? Whatever it is, you have to tell your client (GraphiQL, Playground, etc) to send it together with the query. There's a button that lets you add headers, so you can insert an `Authorization` there, for example. If you share more details about how auth works in your project, I can give a more specific answer.

Comment: I am just experimenting with SPQR at the moment. All I have done is just enabled Spring security in the sample/demo project (https://github.com/leangen/graphql-spqr-samples/tree/master/spring-boot-starter-sample) by adding spring-boot-starter-security dependency which by default uses cookie based authentication. I guess there must be some config to enable/support auth in GraphQL Playground.

Comment: I got it working by adding {
  "Authorization" : "Basic [base64 encoded username:password]"
} as part of http headers. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: @AmitJolly Yup, that is enough if you;'re using basic auth. And that's what Spring Security adds by default.